# 500 error after site was hacked

Tags: ee2, ee1

Website was hacked. After being cleaned up (but probably not 100% secured), all pages started returning a 500 internal server error. Host says it's not them. The server loads flat files perfectly. Moving /system/ returned "The system path does not appear to be set correctly.  Please open your path.php file and correct the path" message, as expected. No idea what's causing the 500 errors. Probably related to the hack, but I can't be sure. Also don't know how to fix it. Any advice?

For context: I don't know if the site runs EE1 or 2. I'm a noob w/ EE. I was called in to help, but I don't know much about the site/server. I have FTP access but (as of now) no SSH access.

**Edit:** A local install of PhpMyAdmin is running on this server. I'm trying to convince the client to remove it. I've moved the PMA directory/files out of the web-accessible directory for now.

**Edit 2, more context:** This site runs on an IIS server. I can't make file-permission changes.

Comment: A 500 error could caused by a url rewriting error. Have you checked the web.config file for any odd rewrite rules?

Answer (score 5):

With any software, it's good to contact the author if a security issue is suspected. If you have not already, contacting EllisLab support about this issue is a good idea.

This would prevent you from needing to post secure information about your site on a public network, and also enable EllisLab to see if EE was at fault, and if there is a security breach in the code that needs to be fixed to prevent it from happening again. EllisLab could help you examine likely targeted files to ensure the installation was cleaned up, and perhaps even coordinate with your host.

[EllisLab Support Center & email contact info](https://support.ellislab.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Check the permissions on your index.php file.

Comment: Permissions say 777 (which is too open, I realize). It's an IIS server and I can't change the permissions myself. I've emailed the host for help.

Answer (score 1):

Can you log into the backend?

If so you can find the information in the footer there. Also, if your login form looks like this then it is EE 2 http://d.pr/i/BvML

If you can't login or load any pages enable debugging to see the PHP errors that are popping up http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html

To enable debugging in an EE 1 site you can't log into, add the following to your system/config.php file:

```
$conf['debug'] = "2";
```

Use this if you can log into the backend:

```
$conf['debug'] = "1";
```

Comment: No, I can't login. I'm pretty sure it's EE1.7.3 now that I've dug around some more. There is no $debug variable as the docs suggest.

Comment: Can you post a gist or screenshot of your docroot layout and another of your index.php file? You can manually add the debug info to the files but something sounds majorly borked if there is no mention of it in your file.

Comment: Is this what you mean? - https://dl.dropbox.com/u/545430/doc-ee-screenshot.png

Comment: Perfect! You should be able to add the debug info to the top level index.php and system/index.php to display the PHP errors... however I think you are on a much older version of EE. That is most definitely not a 1.7.3 install. I would gather that is older than 1.6.8.  What does the system/config.php say?

Comment: Yup, $conf['app_version'] = "168";

What is te debug info I should add? I apologize for my noobile ways...

Comment: Wow....a hacked EE1.6.8 on a Windows server. That's the icktastic trifecta for the morning. (Was just about to suggest you check the config.php file for the version number, but you found that.) I'm of limited help on Windows servers...sorry.

Comment: the styles are syncing now but here you go https://dl.dropbox.com/u/149849/EEDocs1.7.3/troubleshooting/general/blank_pages.html

Comment: Ok, replated error_reporting(0); with error_reporting(E_ALL); but no change. Still a 500 error. Does that mean it's not encountering an error? (At least not at that point?)

Comment: Add $conf['debug'] = "2"; to your config.php file

Comment: No change. Still 500 error.

Comment: It sounds like you need to contact the host or server admin to make sure error reporting is enabled in the php.ini

Comment: Ok. Any idea if an IIS server would still have a php.ini file? Is that standard when running PHP, even on a windows server?

Comment: As far as I know the php.ini file controls the PHP config for the server regardless if it is windows or *nix. That is the only thing that I can think of off the top of my head that would prevent error messages from appearing

Comment: Yes, Windows installations do have a php.ini file. (I've installed PHP on a Windows machine running Apache server software - not IIS - so when in the Apache environment, at least, the php.ini file should be there. You might even be able to edit the php.ini file yourself - check with the host to see if that's allowed for the account your client is using.

Answer (score 1):

If it's telling you to open your path.php file, it sounds like an EE 1.x installation. And if there was a /system/ folder, they probably didn't change the system file name, which means it was easier-than-most to hack into. (Not so great.)

I agree: check the permissions on your index.php file, but also check the config.php file. If they have a backup, try restoring from that. The hackers may have tweaked something in that file...

Comment: Permissions say 777 (which is too open, I realize). It's an IIS server and I can't change the permissions myself. I've emailed the host for help.

Config.php looks ok, but I can't be sure what it used to say.